# Unity Dash not launching-11.10

Tags: unity, 11.10, shortcut-keys, unity-dash

I'm running 11.10. I was on my computer today and I wanted to launch unity dash. But I pressed the superkey (Windows Key) and nothing happened. I pressed the ''Dash Home'' button  but still nothing. What am I going to do? I need dash as it is useful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try pressing Ctrl + Alt + T, if a terminal appears type `unity --replace`. If that doesn't work try `unity --reset` and if that doesn't work either try `sudo apt-get install --reinstall unity`.

If Ctrl + Alt + T doesn't open a terminal try Ctrl + Alt + F1. To switch back to the graphical interface press Ctrl + Alt + F7.

Comment: Cool. The unity reset one worked, and it's fine. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Why don't you accept it as the correct answer then to help others with a similar problem?